# Android version of iOS Quick Look Framework

Tags: android, ios, pdf, ms-office

Is there something similar to the [iOS Quick Look Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuickLook/Reference/QuickLookFrameworkReference_iPhoneOS/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009672) for Android?  I'm trying to display/preview PDF and Microsoft Office files inside my Activity.  I know that I can use Intents to open the files using the associated viewer but I would like to know if it's possible to not leave my application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's only possible if you write your own viewers.  The iOS app is calling out to an external class which just happens to render inside your own view. Not much different to Android except, you use an intent rather than call a specific app or framework which is more flexible since the user chooses how the file is opened.