# Previewing Office Documents in a React Native Android App

Tags: android, react-native, ms-office

Is there a way to preview a local (to the device) Office document (Word, PowerPoint etc.) inside a React Native app using an SDK or library?

I've used react-native-quick-look to take advantage of the quick look framework on iOS, but I'd like to know if anyone has come across anything similar on Android.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that nobody hasn't, according to this question [Android version of iOS Quick Look Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615116/android-version-of-ios-quick-look-framework)

But you can try to send an implicit intent so that the user can choose the app to see the document.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-intent

Comment: That question is from 2012 so I was hoping things had changed since then, but thanks anyway. We're using react-native-file-opener currently to open an external viewer, but that disrupts the flow of our app a bit so I was hoping to be able to render it inside our own app.

Comment: Above comment is from 2016, I was hoping things had changed since then, I don't want to disrupt the flow, don't know what to do next :(